# Read word by word in a variable

Tags: c++

In my code I have to read some words and locate their position on my vector c[100000].
My code:

```
    char c[8];
    char x,carac;
    int main()
    {
                      c[0]='do1',c[1]='re',c[2]='mi',c[3]='fa',c[4]='sol',c[5]='la',c[6]='si',c[7]='do    2';
    cin>>n;
    char x;
    do{
        x=getchar();
        for(int j=0;j<=7;j++){
            if(x==c[j]){
                s+=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }while ((x != ' ') && (x != '\t'));
    s%=8;
    cout<<c[s]<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a 2D Array for strings. You're storing mulitple characters in an array (`c[8]`) , which is defined to hold 1 only character / index.

Comment: only 1 character / index that is

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char c[50][8];
  char x[50];
  int flag=1;
  int res;
  clrscr();
  cout<<"\n Enter Words For Creating Vecter \n";

  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
      cin>>c[i];
  }
  do
  {
      cout<<"\n Enter Search String For continue Search Or '0' for Exit:";
      cin>>x;
      flag=strcmp(x,"0");
      if(flag!=0)
      {
         for(i=0;i<8;i++)
         {
            res=strcmp(x,c[i]);
            if(res==0)
               cout<<"\n The Position is :"<<i+1;
         }
      }

  } while(flag!=0);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I Hope This is the Solution which you Want.